# cors origin missing - symfony ajax - on 2 calls same origin

Tags: ajax, symfony, cors

I have 2 ajax calls to the same domain but the first one result is success. the second one (`foo` function) got the "CORS missing" error and the calls is blocked.

```
              $.ajax({
                  url : "http://box.domain.com/next",
                  method: "POST",
                  data : JSON.stringify({
                      token : token,
                      last_played : last_played
                  }),
                  success : function(d){
                      foo();
                  },
                  error : function(d){
                      console.log(d.statusText);
                      state = "ERROR";
                  }
              });
          function foo(){
              $.ajax({
                  url : "http://box.domain.com/helo",
                  method : "POST",
                  data: JSON.stringify({
                      mac: "addr",
                      pwd: "pwd"
                  }),
                  success: function (d) {
                      if (d.res == 200) {
                          token = d.token;
                          state="READY";
                      }
                  },
                  error : function(d){
                      console.log(d.statusText);
                      state = "ERROR";
                  }
              });
          }
```

the symfony controller has the `$this->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.domain.com');` in the `__construct` function and the 2 calls point to actions in the same controller.

Why the first one succeded and the second one fails?

Comment: You can eventually see if your route only autorize GET Method with app/console debug:router

Answer (score 1):

to solve this I had to put

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.domain.com"
    </IfModule>
```

in `.htaccess` (web folder)